# Fix a slow system with Python

Tags: python, debugging, scripting

The Pool class of the multiprocessing Python module. There is a defined run method to perform the tasks. Create a pool object of the Pool class of a specific number of CPUs your system has by passing a number of tasks you have. Start each task within the pool object by calling the map instance method, and pass the run function and the list of tasks as an argument.Hint: os.walk() generates the file names in a directory tree by walking the tree either top-down or bottom-up. This is used to traverse the file system in Python.

**Multisync.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from multiprocessing import Pool
def run(task):
  # Do something with task here
    print("Handling {}".format(task))
if __name__ == "__main__":
  tasks = ['task1', 'task2', 'task3']
  # Create a pool of specific number of CPUs
  p = Pool(len(tasks))
  # Start each task within the pool
  p.map(run, tasks)
```

The hierarchy of the subfolders of /data/prod, data is from different projects (e.g., , beta, gamma, kappa) and they're independent of each other. You **have to use** multiprocessing and subprocess module methods to sync the data from /data/prod to /data/prod_backup folder.

Try applying multiprocessing, which takes advantage of the idle CPU cores for parallel processing. Here, you have to use multiprocessing and subprocess module methods to sync the data from /data/prod to /data/prod_backup folder.

Hint: os.walk() generates the file names in a directory tree by walking the tree either top-down or bottom-up. This is used to traverse the file system in Python.

Dailysync.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import subprocess
src = "/data/prod/"
dest = "/data/prod_backup/"
subprocess.call(["rsync", "-arq", src, dest])
```

Comment: What is your *question*? This is a series of commands...

Answer (score 4):

Well, for me the

1. I set `src` as global since it is refereced in others functions;
2. Use the full path name `src = "{}/data/prod/".format(os.getenv("HOME"))` instead of  `src = "/data/prod/"`.
3. understand how `os.walk()` works, and access all the values that is needed such as `root = next(os.walk(src))[0]` and `dirs = next(os.walk(src))[0]`
4. If thefolder is empty `Pool(len(folders))` will return 0, and the mapping  requires at least 1 processor so I handled it.

```
 #!/usr/bin/env python
 import subprocess
 from multiprocessing import Pool
 import os
 
 global src
 src = "{}/data/prod/".format(os.getenv("HOME"))
 
 
 def sync_data(folder):
     dest = "{}/data/prod_backup/".format(os.getenv("HOME"))
     subprocess.call(["rsync", "-arq", folder, dest])
     print("Handling {}".format(folder))
 
 
 if __name__ == "__main__":
     folders = []
     root = next(os.walk(src))[0]
     dirs = next(os.walk(src))[1]
 
     for dir in dirs:
         folders.append(os.path.join(root, dir))
 
     pool = Pool(len(folders)) if len(folders) != 0 else Pool(1)
     pool.map(sync_data, folders)
```

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone wants to try this one, this pretty cool, less lines of code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from multiprocessing import Pool
import os
import subprocess

src = "/home/student-01-#######/data/prod"
dirs = next(os.walk(src))[1]

def backingup(dirs):
    dest = "/home/student-01-#######/data/prod_backup"
    subprocess.call(["rsync", "-arq", src+'/'+ dirs, dest])




p = Pool(len(dirs))
p.map(backingup, dirs)
```

Answer (score 0):

This was my final answer, basically:

1: Set the source (src) to the absolute filepath.

2: Traverse the `src` folder with `os.walk()` joining the absolute path to the folder.

3: Create the Pool and map the function to the dictionary

4: Have the function perform the rsync

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from multiprocessing import Pool
import os
import subprocess

# 1 - Set SRC
src = "{}/data/prod".format(os.getenv("HOME"))

# 4 - Pool RSYNC commands
def runprocess(folder):
    dest = "{}/data/prod_backup".format(os.getenv("HOME"))
    subprocess.call(["rsync", "-arq", folder, dest])

# 2 - Set folders array
folders = []
for root, _dir, files in os.walk(src):
   for name in _dir:
      folders.append(os.path.join(root, name))

# 3 Build and run the Pool
p = Pool(len(folders))
p.map(runprocess, folders)
```

Answer (score -1):

I am also new to python and learning from the same course as you. I am attaching the following code that i wrote for the task and it got the job done.

I know this is not the most efficient code and that is why someone more experienced can go over it as well and improve it

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import subprocess
import os
from multiprocessing import Pool

os.chdir('../data/')
list=[]
for path,dir,file in os.walk('prod/'):
        list.append(dir)
list=list[0]
def backup(list):
        src = "../data/prod/"+str(list)
        dest = "../data/prod_backup/"
        subprocess.call(["rsync", "-arq", src, dest])
if __name__=="__main__":
        p=Pool(len(list))
        p.map(backup,list)
```

Answer (score -1):

This question is asking a solution to the **Fix a slow system with Python** test of the **Troubleshooting and Debugging Techniques** (Week 2) course of Google, hosted on the Coursera platform.

In my code, I list all the directories inside `data/prod/` and then I use that list as a parameter to the `run` function that runs in a **Pool** of **Process**, so that I launch more instances of `rsync` in parallel

It is ready to use and you can even just copy-paste it, but remember that **you must change your username** accordingly (it should be in a format like `student-03-12345678`, look at the code comments to change it).

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import subprocess
from multiprocessing import Pool

src = "data/prod/"
dest = "data/prod_backup/"

def run(dir):
    subprocess.call(["rsync", "-arq", src + str(dir), dest])

os.chdir(os.getenv("HOME"))
dirs = []
for path,dir,file in os.walk(src):
    dirs.append(dir)

dirs=dirs[0]
print(dirs) #Used to debug

# Create the pool
p = Pool(len(dirs))

# Start tasks
p.map(run, dirs)
```